# How can I get all values from multiple checkboxes in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an app and for this page I use checkbox. And I want to pick up from users more options. When I click the button, I want to see all checked options.

My .html codes

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of durumozellikleri">
        <ion-label>{{item.ozellik}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="durumozellik"></ion-checkbox>
 </ion-item>

 <button ion-button (click)="getAll()">Click Me</button>
```

My .ts codes

```
 let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type':'application/json' }),
 options: any = { "key": "kontrol", "id": this.id},
 url: any = 'http://207.180.202.55/MisKebap/php/durumozellikgetir.php';


 this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe(res => {

   this.durumozellikleri = res;
 })
```

Comment: i already asking to you ts files :)

Comment: check my post you can see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a field to items in `durumozellikleri` and use that field to store the checkbox value as follows;

```js
  durumozellikleri = [
    { ozellik: "ozellik1", secim: false },
    { ozellik: "ozellik2", secim: false },
    { ozellik: "ozellik3", secim: false },
  ]
```

in html

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of durumozellikleri">
    <ion-label>{{item.ozellik}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.secim"></ion-checkbox>
 </ion-item>
```

here is a simple demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6ecgk

Comment: console.log(this.durumozellikleri.filter(d => d.secim === true));

Comment: bu kod ile sadece checkbox isaretli kisimlari cekebiliyorum sorun yok tesekkurler. fakat sadece 'ozellik' kismini cekmek icin ne yapmam lazim hocam

Comment: `this.durumozellikleri.filter(d => d.secim).map(d => ({ozellik:d.ozellik}))`

Comment: [{ozellik: "Domates"}, {ozellik: "Biber"}]
bu sekilde geliyor sonuc fakat ben bu sekilde degilde , sadece soyle istiyorum
"Domates","Biber"

Comment: i suggest writing in english, otherwise all the comments will be deleted by moderators. `this.durumozellikleri.filter(d => d.secim === true).map(d => d.ozellik)` i updated the demo above.

Comment: Ok i am sorry for Turkish. now i am writing with english. it works perfectly, thanks all everything bro.

Comment: if i need again help, how can i contact with you ?

Comment: keep writing your questions here and someone will eventually answer it as long as you ask well defined, clear questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making the following changes on both your component.ts, and component.html.

On your component.html, you have to bind the checked values of each element in the `durumozellikleri` array to the `ngModel`.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of durumozellikleri">
  <ion-label>{{item.ozellik}}</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button (click)="getAll()">Click Me</button>
```

And on your component.ts, I am not sure the exact structure of `durumozellikleri`, but you should add an additional property called `checked` in each object within `durumozellikleri`. And to get only the checked options, you can use Array.filter().

```
this.durumozellikleri=[
  {ozellik : '123', checked : false},
  {ozellik : '234', checked : false},
  {ozellik : '214', checked : false},
];

getAll() {
  console.log(this.durumozellikleri);
  const res = this.durumozellikleri.filter(obj => obj.checked);
  console.log(res)
  // do the rest here
}
```

Here is a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio-iznxka?file=pages/home/home.ts).